# Access entity methods with getArrayResult

Tags: symfony

I'm experiencing performance issues and I'm trying to retrieve hydrate array with `return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();` from my repository to improve it.

The performance is slightly better, but I can't access my custom entity methods anymore... I guess it's a normal behavior, but is there a way to go through it ?

**EDIT:**
Loading time of my controller is way to long on my local dev environment
[image]

My controller action is only retrieving a set of objects from my repository, here is the code :

```
public function findAllForAdmin()
{
    $qb = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->leftJoin('a.subcategory', 's')
            ->addSelect('s')
            ->leftJoin('s.category', 'c')
            ->addSelect('c')
            ->leftJoin('a.user', 'u')
            ->addSelect('u')
            ->leftJoin('a.advertpaidoptions', 'apo')
            ->addSelect('apo')
            ->leftJoin('a.photos', 'p')
            ->addSelect('p')
    ;

    return $qb
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getArrayResult()
    ;
}
```

a is for advert, I'm retrieving about 2k adverts. That's not so much IMO...
I don't know where to look...

Comment: No, not really, unless you create new methods for your array, so that's a mess. But you have plenty of other options like using DTO, partial obects loading, avoid lazy loading for collections - what is your performance issue?

Comment: @LBA I've edited my post to add some informations

Comment: did you try in a prod setting with logging and debugging off or at a reasonable level? is opcache enabled?

Comment: OPCache is on.  
I'm trying to improve my performance in this simple configuration because I'm having performance issues in prod. I have about 6s of waiting time from the server before displaying anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I managed to improve my performance issue, the answer seems to be pretty obvious though...

Instead of loading the whole entities, I just load the fields I need...

```
public function findAllForAdmin()
{
    $qb = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->select(array(
                'a.id',
                'a.dateCreate',
                'a.title',
                'a.price',
                'a.price_type',
                'a.completed',
                'a.deleted',
                'a.slug',
            ))
            ->leftJoin('a.subcategory', 's')
            ->addSelect('s.slug AS s_slug')
            ->leftJoin('s.category', 'c')
            ->addSelect('c.slug AS c_slug')
            ->leftJoin('a.user', 'u')
            ->addSelect('u.username')
            ->leftJoin('a.advertpaidoptions', 'apo')
            ->addSelect('COUNT(apo.id) AS nb_apo')
            ->leftJoin('a.photos', 'p')
            ->addSelect('COUNT(p.id) AS nb_p')
            ->groupBy('a.id')
    ;

    return $qb
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

The improvement is huge...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`getArrayResult` will return result of select into an array, so it's not possibile anymore to have back your entities.

If you need to fetch all (or certain) infos of the entity, you can follow to strategies:

1. Implicit (at query builder level) make them part of `select` builder's part
2. Use [`fetch=EAGER`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone) on entity attribute

Comment: hm, this is what I tried to say in my comment, but the strategies you're mentioning are just "a shot in the dark" as we say in Germany as long as we don't know what OP's performance bottleneck is.

Comment: @LBA He wrote about "hydrate" and "array": only logic consequence of this is what I've isolated in my answer imho. Of course I cannot be sure :)

Comment: @ThEBiShOp doctrine retrieve time seems to be very little (82ms) and even page render is acceptable: don't know where you lose ~ 700 ms but it does not seems strictly related to query itself. Btw are you sure you want to display 2K result to a single page?

Comment: I have used stopwatch to be sure that the loading time is long at the repository call, my findAllForAdmin() lasts about 900ms. As I said above, I'm using this configuration as a test to improve my performance, I could display my results in a different way, but I believe I can improve it in this configuration. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @ThEBiShOp 900ms seems to be controller time, not doctrine one: check your profiler

Comment: in my controller : http://pastebin.com/V3CPhnag
It tells me 837ms so I think my time loss occurs in my repository, no ?

Comment: @ThEBiShOp: it sounds really strange to me